# ubuntu htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu, lamp

I am on a cloud server using `ubuntu` where i installed a lamp stack and added my server files etc...

but when i tried to access a page like 1.2.3.4/page it will return 404 page not found error...

I am using `Codeigniter` framework.

i tried editing `site-available/default` file and changing `AllowOverride` from `No` to `All` but it will then show a 500 server error

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

... any clues??

**my htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get 500 server error then the problem is not related to access restriction. check the web server log to find errors trace!

500 server error means that your request has been processed (so no restriction issues) but errors happened.

Comment: you were right.. i was getting some errors and then i executed the following command and restarted apache2: a2enmod rewrite which enabled rewrite module... however now when i try to access my server via its IP it adds www. before and it wont let me see the website... just a Problem loading page... any clues?

Comment: Could be Codeigniter url configuration issue? I don't know codeigniter but i suppose it has configuration file for paths and maybe www appears there?

Comment: you can view above my edited post with the htaccess added... you will see 2 lines commented out because i thought these 2 were causing the troubling adding www. before the server IP but its not...

Comment: ok there seems to be a problem with my browser that im using since all the others i tried work... so i think this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions here: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite section 4 has a suggestions for 500 errors.

Answer (score 0):

***Update***

If you get a `500` type of error trying to view your site,this happens because the rewrite module doesn’t come enabled by default for security reasons.

Create a new file called `rewrite.conf` in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`
in the file put this line `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Reload one more time the server.